# How to run a loop in R where it only replaces a variables?

Tags: r

I have a long chain of code below

```
df1 <- data.frame(df1$Group, df1$zL2, df1$ICV, df1$Age)
linearregression <- lm(df1$df1.zL2~df1$df1.ICV)
slope_Extract <- coef(linearregression)
Slope <- slope_Extract[2]
MeanICV <- mean(df1$df1.ICV)
MeanAge <- mean(df1$df1.Age)
ICVCorrection <- df1$df1.zL2 - Slope*(df1$df1.ICV - MeanICV)
df2 <- data.frame(df1$df1.Group, ICVCorrection, df1$df1.Age)
linearregression_age <- lm(df2$ICVCorrection~df2$df1.df1.Age)
slope_ExtractAge <- coef(linearregression_age)
Slope2 <- slope_ExtractAge[2]
Age_ICVCorrection <- df2$ICVCorrection - Slope2*(df2$df1.df1.Age - MeanAge)
df <- data.frame(df2$df1.df1.Group, Age_ICVCorrection)
names(df)[names(df) == 'df2.df1.df1.Group'] <- 'Group'
df %>%
  group_by(Group) -> df
df %>%
  filter(Group == "CN") -> df_CN
df %>%
  filter(Group == "EMCI") -> df_EMCI
df %>%
  filter(Group == "LMCI") -> df_LMCI
df %>%
  filter(Group == "ZAD") -> df_ZAD
cohensD(df_CN$Age_ICVCorrection, df_ZAD$Age_ICVCorrection)
cohensD(df_CN$Age_ICVCorrection, df_LMCI$Age_ICVCorrection)
cohensD(df_CN$Age_ICVCorrection, df_EMCI$Age_ICVCorrection)
```

I would like to run a loop in R where it runs this entire code, but changes zL2 to zL3, then to zL4, then to zL5, then to zL6, then to zL7, then to zL8, then to zL9, etc.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Don't you find this `'df2.df1.df1.Group'` strange? Tip: start by asking yourself what's wrong with your very first code line and try `cols_of_interest <- c("Group", "zL2", "ICV", "Age");df1 <- df1[cols_of_interest]` instead of repeated calls to `data.frame`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dataframe_name$variable_name, you could use dataframe_name[, "variable_name"]. And avoid using the same name for your source and output data.frame (df1).

```
focal_variables <- paste0("zl",2:9)

for (i in seq_along(focal_variables)) {
  df_subset <- data.frame(df1[ ,"Group"], df1[ ,"zL2"], df1[ ,"ICV"], df1[ ,"Age"])
  linearregression <- lm(df_subset[ ,focal_variables[i]]~df_subset[ ,"ICV"])
  ...

}
```